# Specifically change stroke opacity but not color on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a nice tidy script that cycles through colors and it works nicely with the `#xxxxxx` format, but I want to change the transparency. Is there a way to do that?

I'm referring to `ctx.strokeStyle()`

Here's the current code:

```
canvas.strokeStyle = '#' + (((16777215 / s.length) * i).toString(16));
```

It cycles through a for loop with `i` incremented by `1` each cycle and it's a part of a switch. The for loop looks like this: `for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){}`

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517173/change-image-opacity-using-javascript

Comment: @Manoj That seems irrelevant. Isn't this question about `<canvas>`?

Comment: This is the current code: `canvas.strokeStyle = '#' + (((16777215 / s.length) * i).toString(16));` I want it to be partially transparent. @ManojAwasthi It's possible in css and some other applications, but I can't find it in JavaScript for `<canvas>`

Answer (score 7):

You can change `ctx.globalAlpha` in range of 0 to 1 before drawing each element in opacity you need.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ctx.globalAlpha` like Martin Tale answered or `rgba([0-255], [0-255], [0-255], [0-1])` format. So you need to convert the integer to individual rgb values:

```
var color = ((16777215 / s.length) * i);
var r = (color >> 16) & 255;
var g = (color >> 8) & 255;
var b = color & 255;

var alpha = 0.5;

canvas.strokeStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+alpha+")";
```