# Difficulty changing opacity of a javascript line

Tags: javascript, canvas, line, opacity

So I have been working on a neural network for a few hours, and I need a way to show which the weight of each synapse. So, basically, I need to draw a line that is lighter or darker depending on what the input is. I have looked around a bit, but none of the solutions I have found have worked. Here is my code so far:

```
        function line(a, b, x, y, t){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba("+ 255 * t +", "+ 255 * t +", "+ 255 * t +", 1"+");";
            ctx.moveTo(a, b);
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
```

Comment: when you change the alpha value of your rgba strokeStyle does anything happen? [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18251181/648350) seems to suggest you could also toggle `ctx.globalAlpha` between the drawing of each line

Comment: Tried to make t = alpha, nothing happened.

Comment: Tried globalAlpha, this worked! Post your comment as a reply and ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the suggested ways to change opacity of lines, is to adjust the `ctx.globalAlpha` between 0 and 1 just before you draw the line, then set it back to what you need after you've drawn it