# Is it possible to lower opacity on click within a image in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to lower the opacity of a image on click but i don't know if this is possible, at my disposal i have HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: **Yes, It is possible**

Comment: Did you even bother to google this? The amount of times people ask a simple question and wait for an answer vs googling it... As you will want cross browser support.. GIYF

Comment: @Mayhem I actually googled it prior to asking it on here. all of them were using jquery

Comment: all i did was google "javascript change opacity" and the first result was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517173/change-image-opacity-using-javascript which in SO normally means this will be marked as a duplicate and closed by moderators.

Answer (score 5):

Add an **[onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)** event handler and change **[element style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** by passing `this` context as parameter

**CODE SNIPPET :**

```js
function opacity(ele) {
  ele.style.opacity = '.5'
}
```

```html
<img src="" alt="#" onclick="opacity(this)">
```