# How to remove opacity form a thumbnail image

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the opacity of a thumbnail through JavaScript.

I have a very simple JavaScript function for a slideshow. The function works OK for the slideshow but I would also like to remove the opacity of the thumbnails.

The slideshow is dynamic with a row of clickable thumbnails created through the HTML page with `<img src=...>`, the thumbnails are then above an enlarged image of the selected thumbnail. In my code below the "enlargeProdThumb" is the id of the enlarged thumbnail and the "thumbImg" are the thumbnails. I've set the opacity for the thumbnails through CSS, but I would like to remove the opacity when the thumbnail is selected as the source. Is there a way of doing this with a such a simple script, or am I going about it the wrong way.

```
function slideShow(event){
  var thumbImg = event.target || event.srcElement;
  document.getElementById("enlargeProdThumb").src = thumbImg.getAttribute("src");
}
```

Comment: You should try to overwrite it using CSS.

Comment: "Remove the opacity" to me means "make it transparent". If this is the case, `thumbImg.style.opacity = 0` is the literal answer to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change image opacity using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517173/change-image-opacity-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to change image opactity with JavaScript, please read this Stack Overflow post: [change image opacity using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517173/change-image-opacity-using-javascript)

Long-story-short @stecb shared this snippet:

> ```
> var element = document.getElementById('id');
> element.style.opacity = "0.9";
> element.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=90)'; // IE fallback
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a css class selector which decreases opacity and then toggle between adding and removing the class in Javascript.

Here's a sample css for decreasing opacity:

```
.transparent-img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Javascript for adding the class to dom element:

```
var element = document.getElementById("img#transparent");
element.classList.add("transparent-img");
```

JavaScript for removing the class from the dom element:

```
var element = document.getElementById("img#transparent");
element.classList.remove("transparent-img");
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function image(img) {
    var src = img.src;
    img.style.opacity = "0.4";
}
</script>

<img id="myImage" src="thumbImg style="width:100px" onclick="image(this)">
</html>
```