# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'opacity') How to set image opacity via function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating bunch of images with ( let obrazek = document.createElement("img"); ) and i set their opacity to 0.9 with ( obrazek.style.opacity = 0.9; ) and i also add onclick.

Basically I just want to change their opacity to 1.0 after i click one of images, but it doesn't work, error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'opacity').

I tried with obrazek.addEventListener("onclick", zaznacz); , but with this the function itself doesn't work, but there are no errors.

I have JQuery on,

new to JS and I have no idea why this doesn't work.

```js
function zaznacz() {
  this.style.opacity = 1.0;
}

let obraz = document.createElement("div"); 
obraz.setAttribute("class", "obraz");
content.style.textAlign = "center"; 
content.style.color = "#ffffff";

for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let tiles = document.createElement("div"); 
  tiles.setAttribute("class", ("tiles"+i)); 
  tiles.style.height = "40px";
  for(let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    let obrazek = document.createElement("img"); 
    obrazek.setAttribute("class", "tile"); 
    obrazek.style.opacity = 0.9;
    obrazek.setAttribute("onclick", "zaznacz()");
    tiles.appendChild(obrazek);
  }
  obraz.appendChild(tiles);
}
```

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517173/change-image-opacity-using-javascript will help you.

Comment: let n = (i+1)*(j+1);        obrazek.setAttribute("id", ("tile"+(n)));       obrazek.setAttribute("onclick", ("zaznacz("+n+")"));      function zaznacz(id){
    console.log(id);
} this is what i came up with and to my surprise it somehow works. thanks this link game me the id thing idea.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there, but you have some errors here.

There are specific methods for manipulating the class list on an element, so I've changed your code to use `.classList.add()` instead of attempting to set the class list directly as an attribute.

I changed the code that attempts to set the `onclick` attribute to use `.addEventListener()` instead. Note that the event name is 'click', and I pass just the name of the function.

When you create `obraz` your code then attempts to set the style on `content`, which comes up as undefined.

I've added a line to append the elements created to the `<body>`.

I've added a little styling to my test page to help visualise the results, since there are no images.

```js
    function zaznacz(){
        console.log("Zaznacz called")
        this.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";  // Added to help visualise
        this.style.opacity = 1.0;
    }

    let obraz = document.createElement("div");
        obraz.classList.add("obraz");
        obraz.style.textAlign = "center";  // changed content to obraz
        obraz.style.color = "#ffffdd";

    for(let i=0; i<8; i++) {
        let tiles = document.createElement("div");
        tiles.classList.add("tiles"+i);
        tiles.style.height = "40px";
        for(let j=0; j<8; j++) {
            let obrazek = document.createElement("img");
            obrazek.classList.add("tile");
            obrazek.style.opacity = 0.9;
            obrazek.addEventListener("click", zaznacz);
            tiles.appendChild(obrazek);
        }
        obraz.appendChild(tiles);
    }
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(obraz);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .tile {
            min-width:40px;
            min-height:40px;
            border:1px solid grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```